# Custom login forms in xpages?

Tags: xpages

How do I do a custom login form in xPages?   I found this
http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control

in openntf.   Perhaps it is just me but it seems that the documentation is not real clear.  It seems you still need to use an old notes form?  If so it is not real clear to me how his form connects to the xpage.

The documentation does not appear to show what the acl should be set to.  For example if the acl is set to No Access for anonymous, how does the user get access to the login xpage?  There does not appear to be a Public Access property for xpages like there is on a Notes form.

Are there any better examples out there?  Perhaps one with a working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the only way you can get a custom login form is through using domcfg.nsf and a FORM that you point to from domcfg.nsf. This form cannot have any webqueryopen/webwquerysave agents either (well, it can - but they do not get triggered).

However, what the openntf mechanism does, is to use an Ajax call to the server that will be met by the same login - and it has two standard fields (username and password). Therefore, the XPages login-form can "talk" to the real (native) form without you seeing it as a user. Of course, in this way the XPage will have to handle the "exceptions" (wrong user/password, lack of access, etc.)

I hope this gives you a clearer picture ;-)

/John

Comment: Where do I look for this Ajax call in the demo?

Comment: Seems that the old forms are their way out.  Will we see a custom form specific to xPages?

Comment: Hi Bruce. I do not remember where to find the exact calls in the demo, but I am sure you can find it. Search for "username" or "password" - that should put you on the right track. The approach is fine enough to for you to create your own XPages based login form. However, you will need to let anonymous users access the XPage (and all included ressources) and then you can open a url that will trigger a login (e.g. by appending "?login"). That is pretty easy in Java ;-)