# Reason Type field in domcfg

Tags: forms, lotus-notes, captcha, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

To ensure more security to my  XPages web application, I put a captcha in the custom login form in domcfg.nsf.
I followed the link to build my captcha :
http://www.notesmail.com/home.nsf/tip20100506

The problem is when log in, if the captcha is misunderstood , I can not update the value of the field to reasontype it makes me appear the message "Wrong captcha code."
I added this action to check if the text entered is equal to captcha :

`@If ( @UpperCase ( MyCaptchaField ) = TheRealValueOfMyCaptcha ;  FIELD reasontype: = "6" ; "")`

and I added a condition that shows me an error in the calculated field error messages if the value of reasontype is equal to "6" .
This does not work and I can access my XPage even if the captcha is not written.
I feel that the reasontype field depends only 5 predefined conditions.

Is there a solution to add other conditions in log on form?

Comment: You might want to remove the XPages tag, since you're not looking for an XPages solution, but a traditional Domino web solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a space between the colon and equal characters. That means the characters are treated as two operators - a list concatenation operator and an equality operator.

Instead of this

```
@If ( @UpperCase ( MyCaptchaField ) = TheRealValueOfMyCaptcha ;  FIELD reasontype: = "6" ; "")
```

You need this:

```
@If ( @UpperCase ( MyCaptchaField ) = TheRealValueOfMyCaptcha ;  FIELD reasontype := "6" ; "")
```

However, the classic style for this would be:

```
FIELD reasontype := @If ( @UpperCase ( MyCaptchaField ) = TheRealValueOfMyCaptcha ;  "6" ; "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error there...This is corrected code:

```
@If ( @UpperCase ( MyCaptchaField ) = TheRealValueOfMyCaptcha ; FIELD reasontype := "6" ; "")
```

Comment: Yes , thank you for mention That, it was an error in The question. I use The correct function in my form but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

That code is for an old-style Domino web form, not XPages. An alternative would be using an XPages-specific implementation and using an AJAX login post. Here are a couple of OpenNTF I found:
https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Captcha%20Custom%20Control
https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Recaptcha%20Custom%20Control

Here is a blog post which points to another OpenNTF project by Declan Lynch with an AJAX login [Custom login forms in xpages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074049/custom-login-forms-in-xpages)
Here is also an XSnippet for a login custom control (doLogin is the SSJS method to log in) https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dojo-login-dialog-custom-control

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code. But the problem is that it automatically connects to my application and ignore the validation of the captcha.

I found a solution with a redirect to the logout page in the "onsubmit" action if the captcha is wrong and it works and a web alert to avoid the reasontype field.

Thanks for your help.